# Volatility Skew for Put and Call options

Tags: implied-volatility, derivatives, call, put

Given that the implied volatility follows volatility skew, which one has higher implied volatility? At-the-money put 40 (spot = strike = 40) or at-the-money call 160 (spot = strike = 160)?

I am not sure how relevant the volatility skew thing is but still, this question is confusing me so much.

Comment: It is not clear what do you mean  at-the-money put 40 or at-the-money call 160.

Comment: I just added the explanation

Comment: Then you are must talking options at different time, as the spot at the same time can not be both 40 and 160, and the volatility is not comparable.

Comment: Can't we compared the implied vol from different time? For example: How is implied vol when spot = 40 compared to when spot = 160?

Comment: It does not make sense to compare that as the volatility changes day over day in an unpredictable manner.